# Understanding the definition of refinement of a partition $P$.

Tags: real-analysis, set-partition

> *Definition.* Let $P$, $P'$ be partitions at $[a,b]$. We say that $P'$ is a refinement of $P$ if $P'$ $\supseteq$ $P$.

I did not understand really of the definition of refinement. Can you give me a example of $P'$, $P$ and $P'$ $\supseteq$ $P$?

Comment: I guess that a *partition* is just a finite subset of $[a,b]$ containing $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$P'\supset P$ just means $P'$ contains all the points in $P$.  It may also contain some others.  Thus, suppose $P$ is this partition of $[0,1]$:
$$
0 < 0.1 < 0.3 < 0.7 < 1.
$$
Then $P'$ would have to contain all of those same numbers.  For example, $P'$ might be
$$
\mathbf{0} < \mathbf{0.1} < 0.2 < \mathbf{0.3} < 0.5 < \mathbf{0.7} < 0.8 < 0.9 < 0.96 < \mathbf{1}.
$$

Comment: Would this apply to the case where the "mesh" might be finer (but doesn't contain the said points)? For example, $P$ is the partition $0 < 0.1 < 0.3 < 0.7 < 1$ as in the above example, but $P''$ is $0 < 0.01 < 0.02 < 0.03 < 0.05 < 0.08 < 0.11 < ... $?

Comment: @qxzsilver : In your example, it is not true that $P''\supset P,$ so $P''$ is not a refinement of $P$ by the definition stated in the original posting, and in widespread conventional usage that definition is standard. I might, however, say that $P''$ is "finer than" $P$, but not that $P''$ is a refinement of $P;$ however here one should be sure that one's definitions have been made crystal-clear. $\qquad$

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks for your help. I guess this would also mean that by this (above stated) definition that $P' \subseteq P$, that the reflexive property will hold (since $P' = P \implies P' \subseteq P \subseteq P'$. Therefore, any partition $P$ is a refinement of itself (assuming set equalilty holds).

Comment: @qxzsilver : If $P'\subseteq P$ then $P$ is a refinement of $P'.$ If $P'\subsetneq P$ then $P$ is a _strict_ refinement of $P'.\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

For example if $[a,b] = [0,4]$ we may take $P = \{0,2,4\}$. Intuitively, this splits up the interval into two halves of equal length. If say $P' = \{0,1,2,4\}$ then this new partition is strictly finer because one of the two halves itself is partitioned.